# Change Namespace and Project name of a Xamarin Forms project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, namespaces, projects-and-solutions

I need to change the namespace and project name of my Xamarin forms solution including PCL, .Andorid, .iOS and .UWP projects.

If I am not clear about what I want, I will also try to explain it with an example below;

Let's say I created a Xamarin Forms PCL project named myProject. Visual Studio creates 4 projects named myProject(Portable), myProject.Android, myProject.iOS, myProject.UWP. Assume I created so much class in this projects that I don't want to rename all of them one by one. (Even if I did it, I am sure there will be some other places that stays same as I ignored them.) What I want is that I want to see 4 projects named mySecondProject(Portable), mySecondProject.Android, mySecondProject.iOS, mySecondProject.UWP as well as I want to see mySecondProject as the namespace of my classes.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess you're talking about the assembly name. To just rename the **namespace** you can select any use of it, `Ctrl + R, Ctrl + R` and type the new name. All explicit references will be updated (maybe it would be necessary to change the xaml references manually). The assembly name you should change on each project.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I replied below answer that offers similar solution with yours. I would be appreciated if you could read it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know any easy way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on the your namespace and right click and then:

**Visual Studio 2015** -: Select “Rename” and enter your new namespace and press “Apply” on the dialog box

**Visual Studio for Mac** -: Select “Refactor -> Rename” and enter your new namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response, problem is not just namespace. In Xamarin Forms, there is a lot of other places which are named with Project name. For example, Assembly Name, Title, Product, Application name, Bundle Identifier etc. Moreover, I need to change the paths of ProjectsReference, the paths in .soln file, the paths in .csproj file etc. Finally (as fas as I know) I need to change the paths to some temporary keys. I was wondering if there is a guide to proceed this properly. Thank you very much

Comment: If they is a need to change so many places and when you miss one of them will cause unpredictable issue in future, do you consider to create a new project and migrate your codes to your new project? If may involve of namespaces, nugets and references changes/update but in my option, it is more safer.

Comment: I was considering it as a last option but I will probably have to create a new project and try to import my existing codes into it, thanks for the suggestion